# Gradle 5 QueryDsl Generating Duplicate Classes

Tags: gradle, querydsl

I am using queryDsl to generate Q classes with Gradle. It used to work fine with Gradle 3.5, but on upgrading to Gradle 5.5.1, it is failing with duplicate class error.

My generateQueryDsl task works fine generating the classes under 'gensrc/' but on compileJava, the classes are generated again under 'build/generated/' which ends up giving duplicate class error.

```
dependencies { 

   api("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa") {
        exclude group: "org.hibernate", module: "hibernate-entitymanager"
        exclude group: "org.hibernate", module: "hibernate-core"
        exclude group: "org.apache.tomcat", module: "tomcat-jdbc"
    }
    api("com.zaxxer:HikariCP:${hikaricpVersion}")

    api("com.h2database:h2:1.4.193")
    api("mysql:mysql-connector-java")
    api("com.microsoft.sqlserver:sqljdbc42:6.0.8112")
    api("org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa")
    api("org.springframework:spring-jdbc")
    api("org.springframework:spring-orm")
    api("org.eclipse.persistence:javax.persistence:${eclipseLinkPersistenceVersion}")
    api("org.eclipse.persistence:eclipselink:${eclipseLinkVersion}")
    api("org.eclipse.persistence:org.eclipse.persistence.jpa:${eclipseLinkVersion}")

    api("com.mysema.querydsl:querydsl-sql:${queryDslVersion}")
    api("com.mysema.querydsl:querydsl-jpa:${queryDslVersion}")
    api("com.mysema.querydsl:querydsl-apt:${queryDslVersion}")

               annotationProcessor('com.mysema.querydsl:querydsl-apt:3.7.4:jpa')
               annotationProcessor("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa")

} 

task generateQueryDSL(type: JavaCompile, group: 'build) {

                source = sourceSets.main.java
                classpath = configurations.compileClasspath
                options.annotationProcessorPath = configurations.annotationProcessor
                destinationDir = file('gensrc/main/java')

        }

        compileJava {
                dependsOn generateQueryDSL
        }

error: duplicate class: com.persistence.domain.model.QOrganizationBasedModel



and likewise for all generated classes
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you use the `annotationProcessor` configuration, the default `compileJava` task adds the processor to the compiler, and it will generate classes in `build/generated/sources/annotationProcessor/java/main`.

In your case, you also declare an additional `JavaCompile` task, which you give the same annotationProcessor configuration, which will then generate the same classes again.

To solve this, I would simply delete `generateQueryDSL` task entirely as `compileJava` most likely does everything you need already. And if you like the generated sources in a different folder, you can do that through [CompileOptions](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.CompileOptions.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.CompileOptions:annotationProcessorGeneratedSourcesDirectory), but I would recommend having them under the build folder for most cases.

Comment: Thank you :) That's correct. The compileJava task does generate the classes and hence executing both compileJava and generateQueryDsl leads to duplicate classes.

Comment: @BjornVester I as having similar issue. I have removed `generateQueryDSL`, however, I am still getting the same issue (i.e. `error: Attempt to recreate a file for type foo.bar.QClass`. Do I need to change anything else as well?

Comment: I don't think so, but it's hard to say without more information. If you run Gradle through IntelliJ and are using an old version, try upgrading to the latest as there were some bug-fixes for this in the 2019.x series.